# What is the thing Sakura is carrying?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

In the [first opening sequence](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI99Wjba8H4) of Cardcaptor Sakura, towards the end she is shown carrying some sort of object which has written on it "SAKURA" in blue.

[image]

It seems to be tied to her hand or something. Apart from the letters, it seems to be orange, though it may have been intended to be transparent. I think I've seen the same thing in at least one of the episodes, though I don't remember which and I don't remember it being explained there. I really can't tell what it's supposed to be.

**What is the object in Sakura's left hand in the above image?**

Comment: I only ever saw one episode of this so i wont post an answer, but the answer is: A Bag. It is not deflated so she carries something in it, maybe something she uses in the series or maybe it has no purpose and acts as an accessory.

Comment: @曾気青昭雄 I thought that too, but the way it moves in the scene is a bit unnatural if it's something flexible like a bag. It seems to be animated as a stiff, fairly flat object. It's also strange that it would be aligned perfectly for the "SAKURA" to remain readable throughout the scene. That could just be laziness on the animators part, so it's certainly possible that it's a bag, but I think it needs some further confirmation.

Comment: The purpose is never shown but I always thought it was a bag of soft french bread or something similar. That would explain it's shape and how it's still flexible. There is however no evidence to support that theory hence I did not post this as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the comments by 曾気青昭雄 and Raxon suggest, this is indeed a bag. This bag was featured as the point in the Kero-chan check at the end of episode 10 of the anime:

[image]

In this segment, it is explained by  that Sakura uses this bag as a case to carry the baton she uses for her cheerleading. The letters "SAKURA" are embroidered on the bag. It was made by Sakura's father.